# c++ allocator error in ios

Tags: c++, ios

My iPhone app is using a 3rd party software written in c++.
I have received many error reports with such a stack trace:

```
0    libsystem_kernel.dylib 
__pthread_kill + 8
1
libsystem_pthread.dylib 
pthread_kill + 58
2
libsystem_c.dylib   
abort + 76
3
libc++abi.dylib 
abort_message + 74
4
libc++abi.dylib 
default_terminate_handler() + 198
5
libobjc.A.dylib 
_objc_terminate() + 228
6
libc++abi.dylib 
std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 78
7
libc++abi.dylib 
__cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*)
8    libc++abi.dylib    
operator new(unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
9
MyApp   
new_allocator.h line 91
void std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::_M_range_insert<char const*>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > >, char const*, char const*, std::forward_iterator_tag)
```

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
void FileDownloadClient::__OnDataArrival( const char * pData ,int nDataLen )
{
     ....

     m_received_data.insert(m_received_data.end(),pData,pData+nDataLen); //Offending line that crashes

     ....
}
```

m_received_data is declared as an instance variable of type `std::vector<uint8>`

Does anyone know what might be the problem or how to approach this problem at all?
Let me know if you need other information. Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: The most likely cause is that `__OnDataArrival` is being called with an invalid `pData` pointer or an excessive `nDataLen`.

Comment: ...or with `nDataLen < 0`, possibly after a receive error.